# prevent Qlik default "replace with" and "convert to" when dropping extension on sheet

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression

I am developing a Qlik extension whose purpose will be to export charts. I want to prevent the Qlik default behavior of "replacing with" and "converting to" when dropping my custom objects "extension" onto an active sheet. I did not see any thing on Qlik documentation that address this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think this is possible ... imo. This is a "feature" of the client/the Hub and its not controlled by the extension.

Comment: appreciate your answer. I found workaround.